# Subdomain instead of resource-plural as url base for controller/routing logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Sorry if my title isn't clear enough.
In my app I have a blogs resource. Now, normally this could turn out like "www.example.com/blogs/new", "www.example.com/blogs/the-internet-blog" etc. but what I want is to move the "blogs" from behind the .com to being a subdomain. ("blogs.example.com/new", "blogs.example.com/the-internet-blog").

Do I now really need to route all my actions basically manually or is there an option for a rest resource to make it aware of that tiny url logic change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a subdomain in your Rails routes, using a `:subdomain` constraint as described in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints):

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  resources :photos
end
```

And to construct links using subdomains, you can use the `url_for` extension described in this ASCIICast post:

> [Subdomains in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Stuart M's answer I got it to work now, I also was missing the important path-option.

These are my routes now for the blog logic:

```
constraints :subdomain => "blogs" do
  resources :blogs, :path => "/"
end
```